# Upanayanam Ritual

Tags: upanayanam

As as child I underwent the Upanayan / Janayu ritual at 14/15 years of age in the Shree Jagannath Mandir adjecent places by some Panda ji in Puri dhaam. The ceremony was not done exactly according to my wishes, as I didn't like religious concept then (actually no one in my family taught me this stuff then); but as a family tradition. So after the ceremony, I didn't continue wearing it.

Now after having understood (to some extent) the concept of Sanatan Dharm, and having read the holy texts (Gita, Purans etc.) and doing Ishwar Pujan, I want to undergo the ritual once more, as I follow the way of the Dharm now.

Can anyone tell me how the ritual and the process should be done? I am 32 now.

Namaskaram.

Comment: For this you have to contact your family priest or any local priest. They can guide you the best.